# JavaScript creating array with input name and values

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

I was formulating this question:
Is it possible to make an array automatically from the `.name` and `.value` data used in all the inputs type text?

This is the reference doing manually:

```
var foo = [];
foo['bar'] = 'foo data';
foo['foo'] = 'bar data';
```

I got this idea... And it works...

```
var foo[];
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('input').length; i++)
{
    foo[document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].name] = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value;
};
```

The mission was to make it work automatically.
Get the `.name` of the input and get the `.value` of that input.

I was editing the question to post it here... When I figured out how to make it. I decided to leave here the reference, it'll be useful for someone, I guess.

Feedback is welcome.

Comment: @adeneo In JavaScript arrays **are** objects

Comment: No, in JavaScript arrays are arrays, of the *type* object.

Comment: And What's the point in creating another array when you already have that information in your first loop?

Comment: You might want to reformulate your question. Do you want to create an Array object (arrays are special objects in JS) or do you simply want an object with key/value pairs. Your example looks like an object with key/value pairs. Also it would be good to know what you aim to do. Your idea might be good, but maybe you are trying to reinvent a wheel? Knowing where it should lead you can be helpful.

Comment: My idea is pass the array through AJAX to PHP... I'll create the variables with a foreach, and then make an SQL Statement to insert into the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is reasonable enough, except for two things:

- Use an object instead of an array.
- Create the list of inputs only once.

So you could do:

```
var values = {};
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
    values[inputs[i].name] = inputs[i].value;
}
```

Comment: What's the difference using an object instance of an Array object?

Comment: While you can use an array for this and it will work, it's not the intended purpose for arrays. Arrays should be used when you are going to use numeric indexes, not as a key-value store. Since you're coming from PHP, you are probably used to the single "associative array" type that serves both purposes. But JavaScript has an Object type distinct from the Array type, so it is customary to use it when you need a key-value store.

Comment: Also note that many JavaScript data types are derived from Object or can be used like an object. For example, a function is also an object and can have properties assigned to it. So you could say `var values = function() {};` and the rest of the code would still work! But anyone reading your code would be scratching their heads wondering "Why is that a function? It looks like you're just using it as an object." The same goes for using an array when you should use an object instead.

Comment: Thank you @Michael Geary, this is a good lesson, you make my day, thanks.